# Customise Salesforce 1 Search Layout

Tags: salesforce1-app

Is it possible to customise the search layout for contact in Salesforce 1?
I want to be able to show the Account Name next to the contact when I click on the Contacts Lookup field on Events in Salesforce 1.

Tia. Lily